# Embedding excel in a webpage

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-office, add-in

I have read from Microsoft [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embed-your-Excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-SharePoint-or-OneDrive-for-Business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773) that I can embed an excel sheet in a webpage. I have also read where I can embed a visio instance.  Does anyone know if I can create a website that uses an excel instance and visio instance that is unique to each user's experience and draws from their custom database.

For example: say I have a pre-formatted excel sheet with fixed columns and I ask for the user to import their report card, and they do so.  The database stores their report card information and outputs it to the excel spreadsheet instance.

Is this a possibility or can I only embed one single excel workbook that will be linked to the master and can not be customized for each user's experience of my webpage/web app?

It would be really cool if I could do the same with Visio as well.  I have tried to find an exact answer to this, but I can not get a clearly defined differentiation of whether or not I can get unique instances, or whether all must be viewing the same master document.

Comment: Please don't do this. It will effectively require the client to have Excel or whatever installed. Think about Linux, Mac, mobile users..

Comment: @EugeneSh. The article that Brian linked to talks about essentially an `<iframe>` to the Office 365 web-based Excel, and not the old-school ActiveX or OLE-based document embedding technique.

Comment: I do not really mind if it means the user must have Excel.  It is for a very niche industry and market.  I'm currently just creating an add-in, but it would be cool if I could make it 100% cloud server web based.

Comment: It's either that, or create a fairly complex table, and visio type drawing atmosphere in javascript.  Which is definitely not trivial, but possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need some non-free office server product to be able to do that (edit excel docs online). That can be SharePoint, OneDrive for Business (which is basically just another name for SharePoint), or Office Online server (the underlying technology).

Given that you have that in place, the rest is pretty easy - you can create a document per user, and just display it in IFRAME (you can google "WopiFrame" on how to do that exactly).

On the server, in principle, you can bind your Excel sheets to Visio drawings. So that when you edit the sheet, corresponding Visio drawing view is updated. Keep in mind, that is probably possible within a single SharePoint site.

Means, from M$ side, probably the assumed approach could be, you embed Excel and Visio frames in a web page, then embed that page into a SharePoint site, then host that on SharePoint online, and then pay for that on regular basis :)

If you don't want SharePoint, you can still go with Office Online to enable Excel editing in IFRAME on your own site; but here you'll loose Visio rendering, as it's only available in SP. And you'll need to build you own API. AFAIK, viewing office docs is free, editing is not (requires end-user office licensing). In case you would like to go this path, you could start over here: https://wopi.readthedocs.io/

Comment: How about if the user wants many different excel sheets, so they may create hundreds of instances of this over the course of time.  Is that feasible?

Comment: You can create sheets programmatically... as many as you want.